# No está autorizado a cambiar la propiedad 'ConnectionString'. El estado actual de la conexión es abierta

Tags: vb.net

Tengo este problema: No está autorizado a cambiar la propiedad 'ConnectionString'. El estado actual de la conexión es abierta.

Si comento la segunda función si que me funciona pero no me rellena el combobox que necesito.

```
Public Sub conexion_odbc_camisetas(ByVal DatagridView As DataGridView, ByVal EnableDatagrid As Boolean)
    conn.ConnectionString = "Dsn=ODC_Camiseta;uid=xxxxx;pwd=xxxxx"
    conn.Open()
    Try
        Dim ComandoODBC As New Odbc.OdbcCommand(query, conn)

        If EnableDatagrid Then
            Dim Adaptador As New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(ComandoODBC)
            Dim DataTable As New DataTable
            Adaptador.Fill(DataTable)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = DataTable
        Else
            Dim Adaptador As New Odbc.OdbcCommand
            Adaptador.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            Adaptador.CommandText = query
            Adaptador.Connection = conn
            Adaptador.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Tambien tengo esta otra conexion(esta conexion la uso para rellenar un combobox en otro tabcontrol) que es con la que hace interferencia:

```
    Private Sub conexion_odbc_camiseta_llenar_combo()
    conn.ConnectionString = "Dsn=ODC_Camiseta;uid=xxxxx;pwd=xxxxx"
    conn.Open()
    Try
        Dim ComandoODBC As New Odbc.OdbcCommand(query, conn)
        Dim DT As DataTable
        Dim DA As New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter
        Dim Adaptador As New Odbc.OdbcCommand
        Adaptador.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Adaptador.CommandText = query
        Adaptador.Connection = conn
        DA.SelectCommand = Adaptador
        DT = New DataTable
        DA.Fill(DT)
        ComboBox_intrlote_camiseta.DataSource = DT
        ComboBox_intrlote_camiseta.DisplayMember = "Nombre"
        ComboBox_intrlote_camiseta.ValueMember = "ID"
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```